# Why has my ul element disappeared when I utilize the float: right propriety in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Why does my `ul` element disappear when I utilize the `float: right` property in CSS?

I am building the navigation for this website.

You will find the code here in a CodePen:

https://codepen.io/maximo890/pen/JygeVr

**CSS**

```
/*-----------------------------------*/
/* HEADER */
/*-----------------------------------*/

header {
    background-color: #de654e;
}

.logo-link h1 {
    font-family: "lobster", sans-serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    padding: 2% 0 2% 6%;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.menu-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant code in your question, rather than just a link to an external site. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use flex property as much as possible as it's future in works great for responsive behaviour.
For current I see in header you have logo on left and navigation on right and your html is like:

```
<header>
        <nav>

            <a href="#" class="logo-link"><h1>Creative</h1></a>
            <ul><li>...
```

So you can try this:

```
nav { 
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: I tried you css and it's working. Thank you ravinder!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because when you add the float property to all children of an element, the parent will have no height so the links will appear to be outside the header and the links blend with the background of the page. To fix this you could add to menu-navigation this:

```
overflow:auto
```

But I would recommend you to use other techniques like flexbox or using inline-block to build the layout.

You can read more information about floats here:
https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-3